# Swap disk driver on the fly

Tags: drivers, usb-drive, hot-plug

When recovering a failing hard drive, sometimes I need to switch between using `uas` and `usb-storage`. The way I do that is by piping the device port to `unbind`, setting the `u` flag in `/sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks` and then reattaching to `usb_storage`.

If you look at the output in `dmesg` you can see that the operation succeeds, but the device node (and even the device `maj:min`) disappears. How can I reregister the disk?